# MariaDB - Mysqld got signal 6

Tags: mariadb

El servicio mariadb ha empezado a caerse y ahora directamente es incapaz de iniciar. El servidor estaba en funcionamiento hasta hace unas horas con varias webs en producción.

Mi log

```
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140666738792192 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace ID 0 name innodb_system:Default tablespace encryption mode scheme unencrypted
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 67340250070
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 67341514930
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 20 row operations to undo
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 566682112
2018-12-18 20:12:06 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
2018-12-18 20:12:07 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Apply batch completed
2018-12-18 20:12:07 140667795601600 [Note] InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 566681644, 20 rows to undo
2018-12-18 20:12:07 0x7fefc5fcf8c0  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140667795601600 in file fut0lst.ic line 85
InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
181218 20:12:07 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.2.3-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 467199 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x48c00
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x55a8ceabd71e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x2e5)[0x55a8ce4f7885]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf370)[0x7fefc5be5370]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7fefc3ebf1d7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7fefc3ec08c8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x414cd6)[0x55a8ce2bccd6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x416e1e)[0x55a8ce2bee1e]
mysys/stacktrace.c:268(my_print_stacktrace)[0x55a8ce91b895]
sql/signal_handler.cc:166(handle_fatal_signal)[0x55a8ce91bb48]
fut/fut0lst.cc:303(flst_insert_before(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, mtr_t*))[0x55a8ce7dbf51]
include/ut0lst.h:333(trx_undo_update_cleanup(trx_t*, trx_undo_ptr_t*, unsigned char*, bool, unsigned long, mtr_t*))[0x55a8ce8111df]
trx/trx0trx.cc:1676(trx_write_serialisation_history(trx_t*, mtr_t*))[0x55a8ce807ad3]
trx/trx0trx.cc:2192(trx_commit_low(trx_t*, mtr_t*))[0x55a8ce80a0ab]
include/dyn0buf.h:198(dyn_buf_t<512ul>::erase())[0x55a8ce80ab89]
bits/stl_tree.h:858(trx_rollback_or_clean_recovered(unsigned long))[0x55a8ce7f91c5]
include/dyn0buf.h:198(dyn_buf_t<512ul>::erase())[0x55a8ce6ebd9b]
srv/srv0start.cc:2286(innobase_start_or_create_for_mysql())[0x55a8ce7cb7b5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x7dcc80)[0x55a8ce684c80]
handler/ha_innodb.cc:4719(innobase_init(void*))[0x55a8ce4f9ba4]
sql/sql_plugin.cc:1415(plugin_initialize(st_mem_root*, st_plugin_int*, int*, char**, bool))[0x55a8ce381005]
sql/sql_plugin.cc:1689(plugin_init(int*, char**, int))[0x55a8ce38289a]
sql/mysqld.cc:5293(init_server_components())[0x55a8ce2e07f8]
sql/mysqld.cc:5884(mysqld_main(int, char**))[0x55a8ce2e4b7d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fefc3eabb35]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x43155d)[0x55a8ce2d955d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Estado actual:

```
root: service mariadb status -l
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-12-18 20:25:23 CET; 1min 15s ago
  Process: 4881 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4865 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4863 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4881 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "InnoDB: Apply batch completed"
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service

Dec 18 20:25:21 ns346989.ip-91.eu systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Dec 18 20:25:22 ns346989.ip-91 mysqld[4881]: 2018-12-18 20:25:22 140292308601024 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.2.3-MariaDB) starting as process 4881 ...
Dec 18 20:25:23 ns346989.ip-91 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 18 20:25:23 ns346989.ip-91 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Dec 18 20:25:23 ns346989.ip-91 systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Dec 18 20:25:23 ns346989.ip-91 systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

No hay ningún servicio mariadb o mysql activo.
¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Cualquier ayuda será de agradecer.

Comment: Todo indica que la causa del problema es por corrupción de datos. Algunos enlaces, la mayoría referidos a MySQL, que puden ser útiles: [Bug 1172070 - Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL ...](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1172070), [Dealing with Assertion failure in file fut0lst.ic ...](https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=31176) y [A solution for MySQL Assertion failure ...](https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2014/01/25/solution-mysql-assertion-failure-fil_null/). El inglés no será problema, [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/945874/mysqld-got-signal-6).